# How to fix the problem with showing JPanel element in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I have problem with showing JPanel (Page) element that located in another JPanel element in JFrame.

[image]

Abstract Class Page is extending JPanel and giving it some new parameters.

```java
public abstract class Page extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    protected String pageName;
    protected Color backgroundColor;

    public Page(String name, Color backgroundColor) {
        this.pageName = name;
        this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;

        addKeyListener(this);
        this.setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setSize((int) PAGE_WIDTH, (int) PAGE_HEIGHT);
        this.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
    }

    /* keyTyped method is not needed in usage, so it is empty */
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    /* keyTyped method is not needed in usage, so it is empty */
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public abstract void keyPressed(KeyEvent e);

    public String getPageName() {
        return pageName;
    }

    public void setPageName(String name) {
        this.pageName = name;
    }

    public Color getBackgroundColor() {
        return backgroundColor;
    }

    public void setBackgroundColor(Color backgroundColor) {
        this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    }
}
```

I initial Page object in Game Board constructor and then try to use it in printComponent() method of GameBoard class.

```java
public class GameBoard extends JPanel {
    private static GameBoard instance = null;
    private Page currentPage = new MainMenuPage();
    private JPanel dialog = Dialog.getInstance();

    private GameBoard() {}

    public static GameBoard getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new GameBoard();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        this.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        JPanel container = new JPanel();
        container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        container.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, (int) PAGE_HEIGHT);
        container.setBackground(Color.decode("#333333"));

        container.add(currentPage);
        container.add(dialog);
        this.add(container);
    }

    public Page getCurrentPage() {
        return currentPage;
    }

    public void setCurrentPage(Page currentPage) {
        this.currentPage = currentPage;
    }

    public JPanel getDialog() {
        return dialog;
    }

    public void setDialog(JPanel dialog) {
        this.dialog = dialog;
    }
}
```

When window appears, Page element is not showing, like in screenshot below.
Main class code:

```java
public class GameApplication {
    private static JFrame window;
    private static GameBoard gameBoard;

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        setupWindow();
        createGameBoard();
    }

    private static void setupWindow() {
        System.out.println("[GameApplication]: Creating window");
        window = new JFrame("Dungeon Master");
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setBounds(200, 80, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private static void createGameBoard() {
        System.out.println("[GameApplication]: Creating GameBoard");
        gameBoard = GameBoard.getInstance();
        window.add(gameBoard);
        gameBoard.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    /* Game Init Method? */
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please tell more key details about your code and your problem since your question is scant on text and information, information that would help us to understand both. Also, please don't post your code on this site as an image but rather as code-formatted text since none of us can copy, paste and run an image.  For more on this, please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/522444). Also please check out the [ask] for more on-site best-practices.

Comment: Lots of confusion here. There's a lot more code (particularly the creation of ```Container``` s) than you probably need. Try to simplify it. Most of all, absolutely *never* construct layouts in a ```paintComponent``` method, so you need to get all that out of there right away.

Comment: Post code as text, not images.

Comment: @g00se: fyi, code has been posted

Comment: @g00se I removed those containers, but it did not solve my problem. I think the problem could be somewhere in extending Page and JPanel

Comment: I don't see much (if any) change to the code you posted...

Comment: @ЄгорЧевардін: please post the newest corrected [mre] code in your question, the one where you're not creating components in the paintComponent method. Also, never call setSize in this method. That method should be used for painting and painting *only*, and nothing else.

Comment: the `paintComponent` method can be called very often, always when the component or part of it needs to be displayed (painted) again. You mostly never should create new components or change components inside it. I recommend the oracle tutorials about Swing to see how it is intended to be used, e.g. [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: Do not create/modify your UI structure in paintComponent().

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So I solved this problem, by deleting containers:

```java
public class GameBoard extends JPanel {
    private static GameBoard instance = null;
    private Page currentPage = new MainMenuPage();
    private final JPanel dialog = Dialog.getInstance();

    private final JPanel keyInfo = new JPanel();
    private final JLabel keyInfoLabel = new JLabel("Q - quit the game | S - go to start menu | C - clear dialog");

    private GameBoard() {}

    public static GameBoard getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new GameBoard();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

        currentPage.setBounds(0, 0, PAGE_WIDTH, PAGE_HEIGHT);
        currentPage.setBackground(Color.decode("#121212"));

        dialog.setBounds(PAGE_WIDTH, 0, DIALOG_WIDTH, PAGE_HEIGHT);
        dialog.setBackground(Color.decode("#333333"));

        keyInfo.setBounds(0, PAGE_HEIGHT, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        keyInfo.setBackground(Color.decode("#f6f9f9"));
        keyInfo.setLayout(new BoxLayout(keyInfo, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        
        keyInfoLabel.setForeground(Color.decode("#121212"));
        keyInfo.add(keyInfoLabel);

        this.add(currentPage);
        this.add(dialog);
        this.add(keyInfo);
    }

    public Page getCurrentPage() {
        return currentPage;
    }

    public void setCurrentPage(Page currentPage) {
        this.currentPage = currentPage;
    }

    public JPanel getDialog() {
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

It looks like this right now:
[image]

Comment: the paintComponent ist still - it __must not__ change the state, in particular not change the layout nor the container hierarchy