# How to switch JPanel on key?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I need to switch Page class (extends JPanel), which located in JPanel, when pressing a specific key on the keyboard.

[image]

I created in GameBoard class method (`setCurrentPage`), that will update the page and repaint GameBoard object. But it does not work properly. Here is the code:

```java
public class GameBoard extends JPanel {
    private static GameBoard instance = null;
    private Page currentPage = new AgreementPage(); // change to agreement page
    private final Dialog dialog = Dialog.getInstance();

    private final JPanel keyInfo = new JPanel();
    private final JLabel keyInfoLabel = new JLabel(currentPage.getPageKeys());

    private GameBoard() {
        keyInfo.add(keyInfoLabel);
        this.add(currentPage);
        this.add(dialog);
        this.add(keyInfo);
    }

    public static GameBoard getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new GameBoard();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

        currentPage.setBounds(0, 0, PAGE_WIDTH, PAGE_HEIGHT);
        currentPage.setBackground(Color.decode("#121212"));

        dialog.setBounds(PAGE_WIDTH, 0, DIALOG_WIDTH, PAGE_HEIGHT);
        dialog.setBackground(Color.decode("#333333"));

        keyInfo.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(3, 0, 0, 0));
        keyInfo.setBounds(0, PAGE_HEIGHT, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT - PAGE_HEIGHT);
        keyInfo.setBackground(Color.decode("#f6f9f9"));

        keyInfoLabel.setForeground(Color.decode("#121212"));
        keyInfoLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        keyInfoLabel.setSize(keyInfo.getWidth(), keyInfoLabel.getHeight());
        keyInfoLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    }

    public Page getCurrentPage() {
        return currentPage;
    }

    public void setCurrentPage(Page page) {
        //remove(currentPage);
        this.currentPage = page;
        //add(currentPage);
        this.keyInfoLabel.setText(currentPage.getPageKeys());
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }

    public JPanel getDialog() {
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Here is AgreementPage class, that extends from Page:

```java
public class AgreementPage extends Page {
    private final JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("<html>Are you ready for an exciting quest of adventure and discovery?</html>");
    private final JLabel keysLabel = new JLabel("N - not accept, Y - accept");
    private final JPanel textContainer = new JPanel();
    private final String pageKeys = "<html><strong>N</strong> - not accept | <strong>Y</strong> - accept</html>";

    public AgreementPage() {
        super("Agreement");
        super.setPageKeys(this.pageKeys);

        textLabel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(30, 0, 10, 0));

        textContainer.setLayout(new BoxLayout(textContainer, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        textContainer.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(225, 0, 0, 0));


        textContainer.add(textLabel);
        textContainer.add(keysLabel);
        this.add(textContainer);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        textContainer.setBackground(Color.decode("#121212"));
        textContainer.setSize(PAGE_WIDTH, (int)(PAGE_HEIGHT * 0.5));

        textLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        textLabel.setSize(textContainer.getWidth(), textLabel.getHeight());
        textLabel.setForeground(Color.decode("#f6f9f9"));
        textLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        keysLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
        keysLabel.setSize(textContainer.getWidth(), keysLabel.getHeight());
        keysLabel.setForeground(Color.decode("#f6f9f9"));
        keysLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
            case (KeyEvent.VK_N):
                GameBoard.getInstance().setCurrentPage(new AgreementNotAcceptedPage());
                break;
            case (KeyEvent.VK_Y):
                System.out.println("Go away!");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Page class is an abstract class, that implements KeyListener interface and extends from JPanel:

```java
public abstract class Page extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    private String pageKeys;
    protected String content;
    protected JLabel labelName = new JLabel();

    public Page(String name) {
        addKeyListener(this);
        this.setFocusable(true);

        labelName.setText(name);
        labelName.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 0, 0, 0));

        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        this.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 20, 0, 20));

        this.add(labelName);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        labelName.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 36));
        labelName.setForeground(Color.decode("#f6f9f9"));
        labelName.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        labelName.setSize(this.getWidth(), labelName.getHeight());
    }

    /* keyTyped method is not needed in usage, so it is empty */
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    /* keyTyped method is not needed in usage, so it is empty */
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public abstract void keyPressed(KeyEvent e);

    public String getPageName() {
        return labelName.getText();
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getPageKeys() {
        return pageKeys;
    }

    public void setPageKeys(String pageKeys) {
        this.pageKeys = pageKeys;
    }
}
```

Here is code of window initializing:

```java
private static void setupWindow() {
        System.out.println("[GameApplication]: Creating window");
        window = new JFrame("Dungeon Master");
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setBounds(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        createGameBoard();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void createGameBoard() {
        System.out.println("[GameApplication]: Creating GameBoard");
        GameBoard gameBoard = GameBoard.getInstance();
        window.add(gameBoard);
        gameBoard.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
```

I had an idea to extend GameBoard class from the JFrame, but not from the JPanel class, and it will make my life much easier, am I right?

Comment: You should use Swing components and not extend them.  You only extend a Swing component when you override one or more of the class methods.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc , thanks for recommendation. But it does not solve my problem. I need to extend classes, so I can easier manipulate elements in the window.

Comment: well, why didn't you learn from your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73997328/how-to-fix-the-problem-with-showing-jpanel-element-in-java-swing - at least not completely ;) repeating: you __must not__ change the state of the component in paintComponent! Not the layout, not its state, not the children's state (which is particularly rotten, paintComponent is about painting the current component, irrespective of its children/context), __nothing__. Hope that your self-answer implies that fact (you might consider clarifying it)

Answer (score -1):

It solved my problem:

```java
public void setCurrentPage(Page page) {
        remove(currentPage);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
        this.currentPage = page;
        add(currentPage);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
        this.keyInfoLabel.setText(currentPage.getPageKeys());
        currentPage.requestFocus();
    }
```

Comment: (1-) 1. You should be using a `CardLayout` to swap panels. Read the Swing tutorial on Layout Managers[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html] for more information. 2) You should NOT use a KeyListener to swap the panels. Instead you should be using `Key Bindings`. The tutorial link from above also contains a section on Key Bindings.